# SSRS 2017 edit htmlViewer.css

Tags: css, reportviewer, ssrs-2017

As I want to change the layout of the report viewer, I edit the `htmlviewer.css` which is saved under `<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Styles`. But After i modified it, nothing was changed in the layout, why ? do i need to do something before applying it to the report viewer?

I made this change

```
.MSRS-RVC .ParametersFrame {
border: 1px solid;
```

}
to

```
.MSRS-RVC .ParametersFrame {
border: 1000px solid;
width:800px;
```

}

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [only style changing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal?view=sql-server-2017) I'm aware of that is allowed in SSRS 2017

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space in between : and 800
width:800px;

Should look like this

width: 800px;

It's very sensitive, give it a try.